# How to logout from amazon cognito javascript and clear cached identityId

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So far I have managed to login to cognito and syncing data but am stuck at signing out users. Am able to logout from identity providers but upon login again to cognito I get an error for invalid logins. When I reload the app though it works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/609) has been created for this.  The current workaround is to clear the cached id in your Cognito Credentials object, and then to re-initialize it:

```
cognitoCredentials.clearCachedId();
cognitoCredentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(cognitoParams);
AWS.config.credentials = cognitoCredentials;
```

Where cognitoParams is the object used to initialize the credentials, eg.:

```
cognitoParams = {
  IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:ebee2fff-acde-4382-a090-5990604a007d'
};
```

Comment: just setting `cognitoCredentials ` to `null` seemed to do the trick for me (after I called `clearCachedId()`)

Answer (score 1):

After logging out from the identity providers, try calling **[clearCachedId()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html#clearCachedId-property)** on the **CognitoIdentityCredentials** provider. It should look something like:

`AWS.config.credentials.clearCachedId();`

Comment: Unfortunately that seems not to work either. I have multiple logins i.e facebook and google. The problems occurs when I try to logout from either and switch to the other. Am getting the following error{__type: "NotAuthorizedException" message: "Logins don't match. Please. include at least one valid login for this identity or identity pool."}

Comment: @kabangijulius: Could you fix this exception? Facing same

Comment: @BaSha I did not manage to achieve what I wanted but I realised when I reload the app after logout it works. So I ended up reloading after every logout.